# Tradução da medalha Escolar

Tags: debate, status-recusado, medalhas

A medalha `Escolar` foi traduzida literalmente do inglês `Scholar`. No entanto, acredito que esta tradução esteja equivocada, já que estes termos são falsos cognatos.

Enquanto o termo em português *escolar* é entendido, segundo o Houaiss, como: "s. aquele que estuda; estudante", em inglês, o termo *scholar* tem um significado mais preciso e que denota alguém com conhecimento superior. Segundo o dicionário Cambridge, *scholar* significa:

```
scholar: noun
1. a person with great knowledge, usually of a particular subject;
2. also a student who has been given a college or university scholarship
   (= money to pay for studies).
```

A minha proposta é de que o termo seja substituído por algum que se assemelhe mais ao original inglês, p.e., *Erudito*, *Estudioso* ou *Mestre*.

EDIT:

A medalha `Escolar` significa `Fez uma pergunta e aceitou uma resposta`.

Comment: Talvez "acadêmico"?

Comment: Pelo sentido do significado da medalha, acredito que "acadêmico" ou "Estudioso" se encaixe melhor, no sentido de que o OP aceitou a resposta da primeira pergunta.

Comment: Concordo com vocês. Tanto _acadêmico_ quanto _estudioso_ se encaixam bem. Na minha opinião, _acadêmico_ seria a escolha ideal.

Comment: @EduardoMelo quer juntar "Estudioso" como resposta/alternativa?

Comment: @Sergio, claro. Vou sugeri-la pra votação também. :)

Comment: @EduardoMelo coloque a descrição da medalha na sua pergunta para facilitar sabermos o que o nome da medalha deve representar.

Comment: Por quanto tempo fica a questão aberta a debate?

Answer (score 7):

Deixo como resposta para ser votada a [outra sugestão do bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1747/tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-da-medalha-escolar/1759#comment5027_1747), antes da sugestão gastronómica que nós tugas não concordamos :)

### Acadêmico

Na sua versão de portugal seria "*Académico*" mas "Acadêmico" é perceptivel e não fonte de equivocos como "escolar" é.

Comment: Não postei essa porque prefiro transmitir o que a medalha representa, e não traduzir o nome. Acho que qualquer tradução de *scholar* vai soar pomposa demais no Brasil. Provavelmente porque a Academia na nossa cultura seja algo de difícil acesso – e para alguns até esnobe. Como a medalha é para quem está começando no site, "escolar" até que não é tão ruim, apesar de ser uma tradução errada do inglês. Mas tive outras ideias, e vou postar cada uma seaparadamente para votação. Talvez alguma delas agrade a mais gente.

Comment: Hmmm ok, perspectiva interessante, não sabia. E já agora "estudioso" funciona?

Comment: "Estudioso" funciona sim, boa ideia!

Answer (score 5):

Outra sugestão, e que traduz literalmente o termo *scholar* é:

**Estudioso**

Fica como sugestão pra votação.

Answer (score 4):

Estou tentando me descolar dos sentidos que as medalhas têm em inglês. Nessa linha, considerando que a medalha é para quem "fez uma pergunta e aceitou uma resposta", sugiro:

#### Feijão com arroz

Provavelmente os portugueses acharão ruim, aguardo downvote do Jorge B. :)

Comment: -1 acertaste no downvote :P

Answer (score 4):

Minha sugestão #4:

#### Calouro

Esta provavelmente não serve para os portugueses também... Calouro no Brasil é alguém que acabou de entrar na faculdade. Então é uma tradução interessante pois mantém uma ligação com a semântica de *scholar*.

Comment: É o mesmo em Portugal, funciona bem também. `+1`

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão #2:

#### Principiante

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão #3:

#### Engatinhando